# Hide app vertical scrollbar

Tags: angular

I would like to have the vertical browser scrollbar always visible.
In the styles.css I have the following:

```
 html,
 body {
   overflow-y: scroll;    
 }
```

But Angular will show another scrollbar (a disabled one) next to the browser scrollbar

However if I set the overflow-y to auto the browser scrollbar is only shown. 
How can I prevent Angular showing another scrollbar when setting overflow-y to scroll?

Here is a plunkr showing two scrollbars:
https://plnkr.co/edit/yjjFQRgw0fKXPhttcauX?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one scrollbar for the body and another for the html element. If you just want one scrollbar you can use:

```
 body {
   overflow-y: scroll;    
 }
```

Or

```
 html {
   overflow-y: scroll;    
 }
```